# How to find colon separated values from another Table in oracle sql query where clause

Tags: string, oracle, oracle-apex, tokenize

I want to return row value from a Table where another table contain Colon separated value.

Suppose 
I have a Table name "*Unit Name*" that Contain *unit_id*, *unit_name* 
and Table 2 is *User_reg* where contain *User_id*. *user Id* contain colon separator value. Like as `82:81:80`

How can get unit name list from unit_name Table

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    unit_name un
WHERE (select school from user_reg where user_mode = 4) is not null 
and un.unit_id in     
         (SELECT    regexp_substr( school, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL )  FROM    USER_REG 
         CONNECT BY regexp_substr( school, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL ) IS NOT NULL );
```

Answer (score 3):

If you run the following query, you'll have a delimited string converted to rows.

```
select * from table(apex_string.split('82:81:80',':'))
```